# Automatically download emails from Outlook with SAS or Outlook rule

Tags: email, outlook, sas, attachment, email-attachments

I am trying to create a program to automatically download the attached files that are sent to us from a certain email and then transform the delimiter with SAS, of those csv that are attached to us and pass those csv through a flow that I have already created.

I have managed to create a program that treats the csv as I want and the delimiter that I want, the problem is that when it comes to automating the download of files from Outlook it does not work.

What I have done is create a rule with the following VB code that I found on the internet:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\ES010246\Desktop"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

I have changed the path to my personal path where i want the files are downloaded.

website: https://es.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook

The problem is that this code does not work for me, it does absolutely nothing for me and no matter how much I search the internet, only this code appears.

Is there any other way to do with SAS what I want? What is it to automatically download 8 csv files sent to me by Outlook, or has someone experienced the same thing as me with VBA?

I have followed all the steps about 7 times so I think the error is not in copying the code or selecting certain options wrong, in fact I had copied and pasted the code and later I modified the path where I wanted those to be saved. files but it doesn't work, does anyone know why?

I will be tremendously grateful, thank you very much for everything!

Comment: What is the result when you step through with a test item?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to make sure the file name and path doesn't include forbidden symbols.

The VBA macro used for a rule in Outlook is absolutely valid except that a mail item may contain the attached files with the same name, so a file saved to the disk may be overwritten (saved with the same name). That's why I'd suggest generating a file name with your own unique IDs making sure that `DisplayName` property is not empty and has a valid name what can be used for file names (exclude forbidden symbols).

Also you may consider handling the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`.

The `Items.ItemAdd` event can be helpful when items are moved to a folder (from Inbox).  This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.